# Change date format in my HTML / CSS output

Tags: html, css, sqlite

Have a dates saved in my sqlite database in this format 2019-01-24 13:41:40.515955 and when I output to my web page its displayed as 2019-01-24 13:41:40 UTC. Please can I get guidance on displaying something like Wed 24 January 2019 ? No sure how to approach it

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript, would be a simple approach to parse and format dates with desired output.

```
var date = new Date('6/29/2011 4:52:48 PM UTC');
date.toString() // "Wed Jun 29 2011 09:52:48 GMT-0700 (PDT)"
```

```js
var date = new Date('6/29/2011 4:52:48 PM UTC');
date.toString() // "Wed Jun 29 2011 09:52:48 GMT-0700 (PDT)"

console.log(`Year: ${date.getFullYear()}, Month: ${date.getMonth()}, Day, ${date.getDay()}`)
```

You can also parse dates using ``` Date.parse(``); ```